# Жутко лагает CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

Есть задача отобразить данные в виде таблицы. Решил сделать флексбоксами. Получается так: основной **flex-контейнер** (`flex-direction: column`) и в нем много (несколько десятков) **флексбоксов** (`flex-direction: row`). При изменении масштаба или при вводе данных в таблицу проявляется крайне сильная задержка. Сам код написан на **React**, с ним проблем нет. Убираю стили - все окей. Основной **flex-контейнер** имеет фиксированную ширину и высоту (есть горизонтальная и вертикальная полосы прокрутки). Возможно, флексбоксы не слишком подходят для больших данных?

Comment: код покажите - с моих слов вы тоже ни чего не поймёте

Comment: при ресайзе js что-то делает? стоит transition: all на элементы внутри?

Comment: Нет, при ресайзе js ничего не делает. Только элементы сжимаются/разжимаются (ширина указана в vw)

Comment: По коду - в общем-то, ничего необычного. Как и написано в вопросе, есть колончатый флекс <div />, в нем куча других строковых флексов <div />, в них, соответственно, есть кучка <input /> и <select />

Comment: transition стоит, если убираю становится получше, но все равно фризы ощутимые

Comment: Без кода вам не смогут помочь, выложить на любую из js песочниц не составит вам большого труда.

Comment: загружайте пример на codesandbox

Comment: Проблема была не в CSS, а банально в большом объеме данных. Решение заключается в виртуализации.